# How to Convert this curl to RestSharp

Tags: c#, curl, restsharp

I have problem with converting this `curl` request to RestSharp it return 404 error, **note the URL is correct**. 
I think the problem is come from `-d` parameter.

```
curl -v -X POST https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/services/2/transactions \
-H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
-H 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=' \
-d '
<card-transaction xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
   <card-transaction-type>AUTH_CAPTURE</card-transaction-type>
   <recurring-transaction>ECOMMERCE</recurring-transaction>
   <soft-descriptor>DescTest</soft-descriptor>
   <amount>11.00</amount>
   <currency>USD</currency>
   <card-holder-info>
      <first-name>test first name</first-name>
      <last-name>test last name</last-name>
   </card-holder-info>
   <credit-card>
      <card-number>4263982640269299</card-number>
      <security-code>837</security-code>
      <expiration-month>02</expiration-month>
      <expiration-year>2018</expiration-year>
   </credit-card>
</card-transaction>'
```

I did some thing like this:

```
var client = new    RestClient("https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/services/2/transactions");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "Content-Type: application/xml");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");



            request.AddBody(GetXmlToSend(record, CriditCardInfo));
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content; 
            var response2 = client.Execute<dynamic>(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a new `RestClient` you should use the base url, e.g.:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://sandbox.bluesnap.com");
```

Then when you create the `RestRequest` you should be passing the path to the resource:

```
var request = new RestRequest("services/2/transactions", Method.POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

write your xml data to a file, say file.xml

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(remainingPartOfURL, Method.POST);
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(userId, password);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddFile("myFile", "D:\\file.xml");
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

if (response != null)
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

IF you are invoking this code within Office environment then you need to provide proxy server info. You can get proxy server info from Settings->"Network and Internet"->Proxy

```
NetworkCredential aCredentials = new NetworkCredential();
aCredentials.Domain = "";
aCredentials.UserName = "";
aCredentials.Password = "";

WebProxy aProxy = new WebProxy();
aProxy.Address = new Uri("http://proxyserver.com:8080");
aProxy.Credentials = aCredentials;

client.Proxy = aProxy;
```